# Kotlin automatic code calling in delegation pattern

Tags: android, kotlin

I am making use of the Kotlin delegation pattern to mix and match several components into bigger components.  This has sped up my code, made it easier to read, more modular, more consistent etc.  All good things.  However, one thing I'm struggling with is a good pattern to deallocate my delegates.  Most of them have a `dispose()` method that I use to take care of unsubscribing `Rx` subscriptions, canceling Android loaders, suspending execution of tasks etc.  Currently, I am doing stuff like:

```
interface Disposable {
  fun dispose()
}

interface A: Disposable {
}

interface B: Disposable {
}

class AImpl: A {
  fun dispose(){}
}

class BImpl: B {
  fun dispose(){}
}

class Foo(val a = AImpl(), val b = BImpl(): A by AImpl, B by BImpl {
  override fun dispose() {
    a.dispose()
    b.dispose()
  }
}
```

Manually calling dispose on all delegated methods feels a bit clunky - is there an elegant way in Kotlin (via polymorphism, more delegation, etc) to make sure that a class calls certain methods of delegates automatically - in this case, it's clean up methods, but the same could be applied for any operation that all delegates need to do.

Answer (score 0):

One useful pattern will be using `CompositeDisposable`

So you can have some class along this lines

```
val disposables: CompositeDisposable

fun addDisposable(val disposable: Disposable)   disposables.add(disposable) end

fun dispose   if (!disposables.isDisposed()) {
      disposables.dispose();   } end
```

This is inspired by https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture especially the base use case https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture/blob/master/domain/src/main/java/com/fernandocejas/android10/sample/domain/interactor/UseCase.java

Comment: Hm kotlin formatting is not great on stack overflow.

Comment: Yeah, I've used that pattern before in Java and it is great in that environment when you are not looking into elaborating a statically typed architecture. But I am trying to use Kotlin's delegation pattern https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html and it is not possible to do fancy delegation-foo like one does with kaitlin properties (lazy instantiation, observable pattern, etc.). All these things allow you to intervene on the delegated objects but when you delegate to implementations of interfaces you can't do any of this stuff (at least I haven't found out how!)